# Can't login Paypal sandbox account inside sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

i'm having troubles trying to get IPN work inside my sandbox.

I have a developer paypal account and i imported 2 sandbox account. Now i suppose to have 2 ways to test IPN:

1. IPN Simulator
2. Setting my IPN address in sandbox options

but i have problems in both of them.
If try to use the IPN simulator everytime i try to send an IPN page starts loading for some minutes and then Chrome gives me a "empty page response" response. After some googling it appers IPN simulator have some problem with non standard ports but my page can run only on port 12000. My page is reachable, i checked from inside and outside my network, it works for all except the ipn simulator.

I have no more luck trying to set IPN address on sandbox, simply because i have no settings at all to access. I logged to sandbox and got a page where i'm supposed to login with my sandbox account, but i get a different login from mine on the upper right corner of the page (thats the original sandbox account, now that sandbox and main account are merged all this mess happen) and when i try to login with sandbox account i get a generic

> This sandbox mail is not available. Try another mail address

If i try to create a new sandbox account i always get this error:

> We're sorry but something went wrong.Please delete this account and
>   try again.

So.. i'm basically stuck. What i can do to test my ipn now?

edit for be more clear:

- i used to have a sandbox and a main paypal account, now they are merged
- i login to both sandbox and developer section with my main account now
- even if logging in sandbox with my main account i get logged as my old sandbox account
- after this first sandbox login if i try to log my sandbox account (listed in developer.paypal.com) i get that "Sandbox mail not available" error
- in developer.paypal.com i can't create any new sandbox account, getting error everytime. I found that you got that error if password is not 8-20 chars long and now i'm using a correct lenght password but i'm still getting that error

edit2: i successfully created a new sandbox account!
to get that i had to:

- use an US account (i was using italian)
- use password with: uppercase, lowercase, special characters, numbers
- initial balance import < 1000 usd

but i still can't login this account inside the sandbox, always same error. I'm hating this.

Answer (score 0):

Non-standard ports really are not supported at this time, so you'll run into a myriad of different issues over time. The initial IPN delivery may work, but the re-sending of a single message may not, etcetera.

Can you use something like http://progrium.com/localtunnel/ perhaps?

With regards to the account creation:
For discussion's sake, let's stick to the right terminology; you use a *developer account* to log into https://developer.paypal.com/, and a *Sandbox account* to log into https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/

Is the account you're trying to log into via www.sandbox.paypal.com a Sandbox account listed under Applications > Sandbox accounts?

Comment: thank you for answer. I used to have 1 account for paypal and 1 account for sandbox, now they are merged in the main paypal account. I'm logging-in to both sandbox and developer with my main account.
When i log into the sandbox i get redirected to a page but logged as my old sandbox account.
When i log in developer i got my correct account, but i can't create any new sandbox account, i just have my 2 old sandbox imported account and a paypal-facilitator@mymail account

Comment: after login with my main account to sandbox i try to use my sandbox accounts listed in developer.paypal.com but i get that "mail not available" error

Comment: Can you email me the two account email addresses? The one you login to developer.paypal.com with, and the one you attempt to login as a Sandbox account with. My email is in my profile.